# How start GHUnit tests without tapping Run button?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, gh-unit

I use GHUnit framework for testing static library. At this moment I need tap the button Run to start my tests. But I would like to start tests when application launched because I need teamcity launch my testApp. So how can I modified standart UI and start tests automatic?

Answer (score 2):

Do Product -> Edit Scheme… -> Arguments -> Environment Variables, then set `GHUNIT_AUTORUN` to `YES`.

Answer (score -1):

Make your unit test target dependent on your application, so that you always built the application before the unit tests.

Then, simply add a "setUp()" method to launch your app (and wait for it to be launched) before continuing.

1. Check that your application is already running:

   NSArray* apps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] valueForKeyPath:@"launchedApplications.NSApplicationBundleIdentifier"];
   BOOL myAppIsRunning = [apps containsObject: com.mycompany.myapp];
2. Launch your application (in setUP()) and wait:

   [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchAppWithBundleIdentifier: com.mycompany.myapp options: NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation additionalEventParamDescriptor: NULL launchIdentifier: nil];
   while (![self isRunning]) // see above
   {
       sleep(1);
   }